# Java add a JLabel in the middle of a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel

I would like to simply add a JLabel into a JButton and center it horizontally. I've tried many thing but the text stay left side... Here is my code :

```
    JLabel labeltest = new JLabel("Simple test");
    JButton myButton = new JButton();
    myButton.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    myButton.add(labeltest);
```

[image: output picture]

Comment: Try html, `new JLabel("<center>Simple test</center>");`

Comment: Why don't you just `new JButton("Simple test")`?

Comment: Because I need to do some operation with it like     labeltest.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    labeltest.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    labeltest.setOpaque(true);

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you're trying to add a JLabel to a JButton. Any pictures of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: The reason I ask is to be sure that yours isn't an XY Problem in disguise.

Comment: Hint: `JButton` doesn't have a layout manager, even if you solved that problem, it's highly unlikely that the button would even use any child components as part of its sizing calculations and simply appear very, very small

Comment: I've add the output that I get (picture). I can't center the number "3" on this button.

Comment: Create an Icon of the text and give the Icon the foreground/background colors that you want.

Comment: I tried this but the problem comes when I had to do button.setenabled(false); after this the text becomes almost invisible.

Answer (score 3):

Create an Icon of the text and give the Icon the foreground/background colors that you want.

> I tried this but the problem comes when I had to do button.setenabled(false); after this the text becomes almost invisible

You can set the disabled Icon to be the same as the Icon and it will not be painted in the disabled state:

```
JButton button = new JButton( new ImageIcon(...) );
button.setDisabledIcon( button.getIcon() );
button.setEnabled(false);
```

Of course the problem with this approach is that the user doesn't know the button is disabled. So in reality you would need 2 icons:

1. one for the normal state
2. one for the disabled state

Comment: Ok thanks ! But if if their is a timer on the disabled button which has to change every seconds. Is their a issue with this ?

Comment: *"Is their a issue with this ?"* Did you *try* it?

Answer (score 3):

A `JButton` is also a `java.awt.Container`. Thus you can set a layout manager. E.g. you can use a GridBagLayout.

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    JToggleButton toggleButton = new JToggleButton();
    JLabel jLabel = new JLabel("3");

    JToggleButton.ToggleButtonModel toggleButtonModel = (JToggleButton.ToggleButtonModel) toggleButton.getModel()
    ToggleForegroundAction toggleForegroundAction = 
            new ToggleForegroundAction(toggleButtonModel, Color.WHITE, Color.RED);
    toggleForegroundAction.setComponent(jLabel);
    toggleButton.setAction(toggleForegroundAction);

    toggleButton.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    toggleButton.add(jLabel, new GridBagConstraints());

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(toggleButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.add(panel);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

An action that toggles the label's foreground color might look like this

```
  public class ToggleForegroundAction extends AbstractAction {

    private JComponent component;
    private JToggleButton.ToggleButtonModel toggleButtonModel;
    private final Color selectedColor;
    private final Color unselectedColor;

    public ToggleForegroundAction(JToggleButton.ToggleButtonModel toggleButtonModel, Color selectedColor, Color unselectedColor) {
      this.toggleButtonModel = toggleButtonModel;
      this.selectedColor = selectedColor;
      this.unselectedColor = unselectedColor;
    }

    public void setComponent(JComponent component) {
      this.component = component;
      setForeground(component, toggleButtonModel.isSelected());
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      JComponent targetComponent = this.component;
      if (targetComponent == null) {
        targetComponent = (JComponent) e.getSource();
      }
      setForeground(targetComponent, toggleButtonModel.isSelected());
    }

    private void setForeground(JComponent targetComponent, boolean isSelected) {
      Color foreground;
      if (isSelected) {
        foreground = selectedColor;
      } else {
        foreground = unselectedColor;
      }
      targetComponent.setForeground(foreground);
    }
  }
```

[image: Unselected] => [image: Selected]